# Using powershell to send information to a website without opening a web browser

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Is there a way using powershell that I can send information to a webpage without opening a web browser?

for example I would like to execute the following but without a webbrowser ever opening.  I do not care about returned data.

```
  http://www.foobar.org/foo.php?CompName=Baz&UID=quux
```

Comment: Can you use something like: `[System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://www.foobar.org/foo.php?CompName=Baz&UID=quux").GetResponse()`? I'm just writing it as a comment because I don't have much experience with webrequest. However, this would return information about the returning content, which means that the website processed the request.

Comment: I don't know Graimer.  I will give this a try when I get home.

Comment: I added it as an answer with an alternative ;) The last will definately work, but if the first attempt does it's job, it will be faster and use less network traffic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should do the trick(someone please correct me if I'm wrong):

```
[System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://www.foobar.org/foo.php?CompName=Baz&UID‌​=quux").GetResponse().Close()
```

This would return information about the returning content, which means that the website processed the request.

If not, you can always use `WebClient` and just out-null the response data:

```
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadString("http://www.foobar.org/foo.php?CompName=Baz&UID‌​=quux") | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have PowerShell 3 installed.

http://mcpmag.com/articles/2013/01/22/pshell-invoke-webrequest.aspx

```
Invoke-WebRequest  http://www.foobar.org/foo.php?CompName=Baz&UID=quux
```

Comment: this is the easiest ofc., but from the tags it looks like he has PS2.0 :-)

Comment: Yeah I am not allowed to upgrade to PowerShell 3.  I am not even sure if I could.  The company is still using Windows XP PRO.  Yeah I know ancient. lol

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered curl?  You can execute a remote http command with:

```
curl http://www.foobar.org/foo.php?CompName=Baz&UID=quux
```

You can get it from http://curl.haxx.se/

Comment: I wish I could use curl.  The problem is I am very limited in what I am allowed to use on the computers. I am pretty much stuck with powershell alone.

Answer (score 1):

If you're allowed to use VBScript, you could do something like this:

```
Set req = CreateObect("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
req.open "GET", "http://www.foobar.org/foo.php?CompName=Baz&UID=quux", False
req.send
```

Comment: I can use VBScript but would prefer not to; however, this is a very useful snippet to have.  Thank you.